# Printing a mathematical equation inclosed in ()

Tags: python, pycharm

```
first_number = float(input("Enter your first number: "))
second_number = float(input("Enter your second number: "))
third_number = float(input("Enter your third number: "))
result = (first_number + second_number + third_number) / 3
print(first_number, "+", second_number, "+",
      third_number, "/3", "=", result)
```

This code produces this result:

```
4.0 + 5.0 + 6.0 /3 = 5.0
```

but I'm looking to get this:

```
(4.0 + 5.0 + 6.0) /3 = 5.0
```

if I do this:

```
print((first_number, "+", second_number, "+",
  third_number), "/3", "=", result)
```

then as an output I get this:

```
(4.0, '+', 4.0, '+', 4.0) /3 = 4.0
```

so any help?
I'm just starting to learn coding, and this question maybe, I'm sure it is, stupid but if you have an answer that you can share that'd be great!

Comment: put the `()` in `""` like the + and =

Comment: `(` and `)` are a part of Python. It does not understand you want to print them, it is trying to use them in the code. You simply want to refer to the characters ( and ) so put them in quotes as @depperm said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose your parenthesis in quotation marks:

```
print("(", first_number, "+", second_number, "+",
    third_number, ")", "/3", "=", result)
```

Another alternative is to utilize string [formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

```
print("({} + {} + {}) /3 = {}".format(first_number, second_number, third_number, result))
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your parenthesis don't have quotes around them, so they are being treated like parenthesis in python.

This is how i would do it if i were you (Though, the string formatting in @Andy's answer is more of the standard way to do this, so learn it that way )

```
print_this = "(" , first_number, "+", second_number, "+", third_number, ")", "/3", "=", result
```

and then since you also want to output it as an actual formula, instead of a python list, do this.

```
print(" ".join(print_this))
```